# JavaScript to "flatten" a webpage DOM preserving visual appearance?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I would like to write JavaScript code that "flattens" the DOM of an arbitrary webpage while preserving the visual appearance (but not necessarily the resize or other dynamic behaviors)

In theory I believe this should simply be a matter of recording the position of each element relative to the window (e.x. [PPK's `findPos(element)`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)) as well as it's computed CSS styles (e.x. [`window.getComputedStyle(element).cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle)), moving the element from it's parent to a direct child of "body", making it absolutely positioned at the previously recorded position, and setting the recorded CSS attributes directly on the element.

I've had some success with this approach but it's not close to being perfect:

```
function walkDOM(element, parent, nodes) {
    parent = parent || { top : 0, left : 0, depth : 0 };
    nodes = nodes || [];

    if (element.nodeType === 1) {
        var node = findPos(element);
        node.element = element;
        node.width = element.scrollWidth;
        node.height = element.scrollHeight;
        node.depth = parent.depth + 1;
        node.cssText = window.getComputedStyle(element).cssText;
        nodes.push(node);

        for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
            walkDOM(element.childNodes[i], node, nodes);
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}

// based on http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html
function findPos(element) {
    var position = { left : 0, top : 0 };
    if (element.offsetParent) {
        do {
            position.left += element.offsetLeft;
            position.top += element.offsetTop;
        } while (element = element.offsetParent);
    }
    return position;
}

var nodes = walkDOM(document.body);

nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    var e = node.element;

    if (e !== document.body)
        e.parentNode.removeChild(e);

    // e.setAttribute("style", node.cssText);
    e.style.position = "absolute";
    e.style.top = node.top + "px";
    e.style.left = node.left + "px";
    e.style.width = node.width + "px";
    e.style.height = node.height + "px";
    e.style.zIndex = node.depth + 1;

    if (e !== document.body)
        document.body.appendChild(e);
});
```

Comment: This script does what you want, right ? What's the problem with it ?

Comment: It does flatten the DOM but many elements are mis-positioned or styled incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying something similar, but I'm *flattening* only the block-level nodes, as doing all of them will kill the layout (think about an **em** inside a **p**, etc.). So I was walking the tree like this:

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    function (node) { 
        if (window.getComputedStyle(node, null).getPropertyValue("display") == "block") {
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT; 
    },
    false
);

var nodeList = new Array();
while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
}
```

Then just iterate them (as you'll have them in proper reverse order) and move them to the **body** while applying the positioning.

I was for my purposes just recreating simple **div** boxes for them to study the layout, and I found that I get in trouble with block elements originally positioned in other ones that clip them (overflow hidden), I'm currently looking in using svg masks to reproduce the clipping.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I do think my problems arise from trying to flatten non-"block" elements. If I filter those out then it's a lot better, though not as flat. I'm going to experiment with replacing the non-block elements with absolutely positioned divs or something similar.

Comment: In the case of an (em) inline element inside a block one (p), if you take it out the text will reflow; I doubt that you can take the individual text nodes (around (em)) and wrap them in divs to position them. You could replace the (em) with a small dummy inline element with (em)'s width/height just to keep the text in place. Would a flat structure with some dummy nodes be better for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are off to a good start. Have you considered using jQuery for this? They have really useful functions that might make this a tid bit easier for you, especially the offset() function, which gets the elements absolute position from the document.

```
http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/
http://api.jquery.com/offset/
http://api.jquery.com/position/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/
```

You might also try making the elements fixed instead of absolute.